# Como puedo realizar la conversión de una imagen obtenida de mongoDB de tipo binary a Base64 en javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb, spring-mvc

En el siguiente bloque de código se realiza una petición POST al servidor. En caso de que la petición sea ejecutada correctamente enviaremos la respuesta al método `ShowPublication`, que se encarga de mostrar la publicación y es donde interesa realizar la conversión de tipo binary a Base64.

```js
function ValPublication() {
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formPublication"));
        formData.append("Id_Pb",document.getElementById("Ult_Pb").value);
        $.ajax({
            url: "registrarPublicacion.html",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data:formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
       success : function(response) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", response);
        ShowPublication(response);
       },
       error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        display(e);
       },
       done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
       }
      });
    
    }

function ShowPublication(data) {

 dato=JSON.parse(data);

 for (var i = 0; i < dato.length; i++) {
  dato[i].photo;//foto en bynary como pasar a Base64

 }
}
```

Este bloque de código forma parte del servidor. Su función es ejecutar una query contra MongoDB y construir una respuesta en formato JSON:

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/registrarPublicacion", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody String registrarPub(HttpServletRequest request) {
 HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
        ArrayList listPub = consultarPublicationes(0 + "");
   
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(listPub);
 return json;
}

public static List consultarPublicationes(String comuna) {
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 List<Publication> q1s = null;
  
 Date fecha = new Date();
 fecha.setHours(0);
 fecha.setMinutes(0);
 fecha.setSeconds(0);
 Date date = new Date(fecha.getTime()-18000000);
 String dateAsString = sdf.format(fecha); //"08.01.2013"
 //Date dateFromString = sdf.parse(dateAsString);
 //Date ayer = new Date( fecha.getTime()-86400000);
  
 if(comuna==null) { //cuando se logue y comuna esta vacia! --machetazo
  q1s = operation.find((new Query((Criteria.where("date").gte(fecha))).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date"))),Publication.class);
 } else {
  if(Integer.parseInt(comuna) == 0) {
   q1s = operation.find((new Query((Criteria.where("date").gte(fecha))).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date"))),Publication.class); 
  } else { 
   q1s = operation.find(new Query(Criteria.where("date").gte(fecha).andOperator(Criteria.where("Id_Barrio").regex("^"+comuna+"([^ ][^ ])$"))).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date")), Publication.class);
  }
 } 
 System.out.println(q1s.get(0).getPhoto());
    //System.out.println(fecha.toString());
 return q1s;
}
```

**Ejemplo registro (json)**

La siguiente imagen representa un registro de la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo la sensación de que, más allá del título, una descripción del problema y qué hace tu código o qué no hace, ayudaría a que alguien intente leer tu pregunta. Te aseguro que, así como está redactada, muchos ni siquiera intentarán ver de qué se trata

Comment: Gracias! #hecnabae

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar la conversión del buffer `dato[i].photo` simplemente debes ejecutar la siguiente instrucción:

```
var imagen = new Buffer(dato[i].photo).toString('base64');
```

Sin embargo, tal como comentan en el siguiente [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31335758/2131029), no es muy recomendable almacenar imagenes de este modo en MongoDb por diversas razones (una de ellas el limite de 16MB por documento). Para almacenar imágenes o ficheros es más recomendable utilizar [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/).

Comment: Saludos! @hecnabae yo estoy usando springMVC con javascript y al momento de ejecutar la instruccion`var imagen = new Buffer(dato[i].photo).toString('base64');` la imprimo en un alert pero no ejecuta el alert, como si no tuviera nada.

Comment: ¿Has probado a imprimir solo el campo `dato[i].photo`? De este modo podrás verificar que dicho campo contenga la información de la imagen. En tal caso, habría que analizar cual es el motivo por el que no pasa el buffer a formato base64.